# Error in JavaScript scrollTop working

Tags: javascript, html

I want that when the vertical scrolling on the page exceeds 100px, Alert message `hello` should be displayed. I tried doing but it didn't work.

JavaScript

```
function fixSearch(body) {
var a=body.scrollTop;
if(a>100)
{
    alert("Hello");
}
}
```

HTML

```
<body onscroll="fixSearch(this)">
---------------------------
---------------------------
---------------------------
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IE , use

```
 body.scrollTop
```

For the others

```
 window.pageYOffset
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [window.onscroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onscroll) and it might work.

Answer (score 0):

use `document.body.scrollTop` instead of simply `body.scrollTop`, it should work