# Issues regarding scrollTop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want the Alert message `hello` to be displayed when the vertical scrolling on the page exceeds 100px. I tried doing but it didn't work.

JavaScript Code:

```
function fixSearch(body) {
var a=body.scrollTop;
if(a>100)
{
   alert("Hello");
}
}
```

HTML Code

```
<body onscroll="fixSearch(this)">
---------------------------
---------------------------
---------------------------
</body>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565756/error-in-javascript-scrolltop-working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `body.scrollTop` with `document.body.scrollTop`, it should work

Answer (score 0):

The `scrollY` property is part of the `window` object, not the `body`!

```
function fixSearch(window) {
    if(window.scrollY > 100)
        alert("Hello");
}
```